# Android Gradle dependency resolution order

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a remote maven repositories in my app module's build.gradle file. When I run assembleDebug -info from the command line, I can see that gradle is trying to resolve the support library dependencies by looking them up in my remote maven repo, and I get this error:

```
    Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/cardview-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/cardview-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/palette-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/palette-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/android/support/recyclerview-v7/]
Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/maven-metadata.xml]
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/]
```

**Question:** Is there a way to configure the gradle file to stop trying to connect to my remote maven repo to resolve the android specific dependencies? Here's my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        ...

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.+'
            compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
            compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:21.0.+'
            compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
            compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
        }
    }

    repositories {
        //My personal repo
        maven { url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/'}
    }

    dependencies {
        //My App's Dependencies here       
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `+` in your version numbers. If you use `+`, then the build system needs to periodically check to see if a newer version is available. If you specify an explicit version number without a `+`, and if that version is cached, it will never have to hit the network for it.

It was looking in your custom repository because to evaluate a `+` version spec, it will need to scan all repositories to find the one with the latest version. If you specify the version number explicitly, it will scan repositories in the order they appear in the build files and stop when it gets what it wants.

Comment: that will definitely help, and I'll do that. Do you happen to know if there's a way to order the repositories so that the build system knows exactly where to resolve each dependency?

Comment: It evaluates them in the order you have them in the build file and stops when it finds what it's looking for. Since it appears that you're putting your repository last in the chain, it shouldn't be looking there unless it can't find that version anywhere else. In the case of `+` notation, for obvious reasons it would need to look everywhere to find the latest.

Answer (score 0):

That's because there're no android support libs in your private repository. I would add `mavenCentral()` to repositories, so that Gradle will try to resolve dependencies through maven central repo first, then go through your private repo if dependency isn't found in central repo.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    //My personal repo
    maven { url 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/me/releases-android/master/releases/'}
}
```

Comment: I'm using jcenter() instead of mavenCentral() in my top level build.gradle file.